# How do i make an automated traffic light?

Tags: javascript, css

```js
var RED = "#FF0000";
var YELLOW = "#FFFF00";
var GREEN = "#00FF00";
var DARK_RED = "#380000";
var DARK_YELLOW = "#383800";
var DARK_GREEN = "#003800";
var X_ALL = 150;
var Y_RED = 100;
var Y_YELLOW = Y_RED + 150;
var Y_GREEN = Y_YELLOW + 150;
var trafficLightsStateMachine;
function TrafficLightsStateMachine() {
  this.state = 0;
  this.stateMachine = new Array();
  this.stateMachine[0] = function () { drawCircles(DARK_RED, YELLOW, DARK_GREEN); };
  this.stateMachine[1] = function () { drawCircles(RED, DARK_YELLOW, DARK_GREEN); };
  this.stateMachine[2] = function () { drawCircles(RED, YELLOW, DARK_GREEN); };
  this.stateMachine[3] = function () { drawCircles(DARK_RED, DARK_YELLOW, GREEN); };
  this.process = function() {
    this.stateMachine[this.state]();
    this.state = (this.state + 1) % this.stateMachine.length;
  };
  this.drawCircle = function(canvas, color, x, y) {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.closePath();
    context.stroke();
    context.fill();
  };
}

function drawCircles(first, second, third) {
  var id = 'canvas';
  var canvas = document.getElementById(id);
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    trafficLightsStateMachine.drawCircle(canvas, first, X_ALL, Y_RED);
    trafficLightsStateMachine.drawCircle(canvas, second, X_ALL, Y_YELLOW);
    trafficLightsStateMachine.drawCircle(canvas, third, X_ALL, Y_GREEN);
  }
}

function init() {
  trafficLightsStateMachine = new TrafficLightsStateMachine();
  drawCircles(DARK_RED, DARK_YELLOW, GREEN);
}
```

```css
#page
{
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}
#canvas:hover
{
  cursor: crosshair;
  background-color: #191919;
}
#canvas
{
  background-color: #252525;
}
body
{
  background: #222222;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body onload="init()">
  <div id="page" onclick="trafficLightsStateMachine.process()" title="Please, press button.">
    <canvas id="canvas" height="500px" width="300px">
    </canvas>
  </div>
</body>
```

I would like to be able to change this code so that when run the traffic light changes automatically. I know I need to add in `setinterval(trafficLightsStateMachine.process,1000)` however I do not know where. Please advise.

Comment: Can you make this into a runnable snipplet please, best directly here, or otherwise on jsfiddle. I'm sure that someone will help you then.

Comment: What you try to accomplish with the interval? Do you want that the lights will switch automatically?

Comment: i would like the lights to switch automatically between colours

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Remove the init from the body onload
2. Remove the onclick from the div
3. Add an onload event handler like this:

---

```
window.onload=function() { 
  init(); 
  setInterval(
    trafficLightsStateMachine.process.bind(trafficLightsStateMachine),
  1000); // syntax necessary to be able to use "this" in the stateMachine
}
```

Result:

```js
var RED = "#FF0000";
var YELLOW = "#FFFF00";
var GREEN = "#00FF00";
var DARK_RED = "#380000";
var DARK_YELLOW = "#383800";
var DARK_GREEN = "#003800";
var X_ALL = 150;
var Y_RED = 100;
var Y_YELLOW = Y_RED + 150;
var Y_GREEN = Y_YELLOW + 150;
var trafficLightsStateMachine;
function TrafficLightsStateMachine() {
  this.state = 0;
  this.stateMachine = new Array();
  this.stateMachine[0] = function () { drawCircles(DARK_RED, YELLOW, DARK_GREEN); };
  this.stateMachine[1] = function () { drawCircles(RED, DARK_YELLOW, DARK_GREEN); };
  this.stateMachine[2] = function () { drawCircles(RED, YELLOW, DARK_GREEN); };
  this.stateMachine[3] = function () { drawCircles(DARK_RED, DARK_YELLOW, GREEN); };
  this.process = function() {
    this.stateMachine[this.state]();
    this.state = (this.state + 1) % this.stateMachine.length;
  };
  this.drawCircle = function(canvas, color, x, y) {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.closePath();
    context.stroke();
    context.fill();
  };
}

function drawCircles(first, second, third) {
  var id = 'canvas';
  var canvas = document.getElementById(id);
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    trafficLightsStateMachine.drawCircle(canvas, first, X_ALL, Y_RED);
    trafficLightsStateMachine.drawCircle(canvas, second, X_ALL, Y_YELLOW);
    trafficLightsStateMachine.drawCircle(canvas, third, X_ALL, Y_GREEN);
  }
}

function init() {
  trafficLightsStateMachine = new TrafficLightsStateMachine();
  drawCircles(DARK_RED, DARK_YELLOW, GREEN);
}
window.onload=function() {
  init();
  setInterval(trafficLightsStateMachine.process.bind(trafficLightsStateMachine),1000);
}
```

```css
#page
{
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}
#canvas:hover
{
  cursor: crosshair;
  background-color: #191919;
}
#canvas
{
  background-color: #252525;
}
body
{
  background: #222222;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
    <canvas id="canvas" height="500px" width="300px"></canvas>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `trafficLightsStateMachine.process.bind(trafficLightsStateMachine)` since process uses `this`?

Comment: It worked on click because they had `trafficLightsStateMachine.process()` in the onclick attribute

Comment: Just add the .bind() call: `setInterval(trafficLightsStateMachine.process.bind(trafficLightsStateMachine),1000);`

Comment: Updated the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Put `setInterval(trafficLightsStateMachine.process,1000)` in the bottom of the `init()` function.

Comment: Should i still take out the init() from the body onload if i am adding the setInterval(trafficLightsStateMachine.process,1000) into the bottom of the init() function?

Comment: No you still need to call `init()` from somewhere. But it's considered to be a better practice to bind events through code, like mplungjan showed, instead of binding on HTML elements.

Comment: this will actually break the "this"

Answer (score 1):

trafficLightsStateMachine.process()

```js
var RED = "#FF0000";
var YELLOW = "#FFFF00";
var GREEN = "#00FF00";
var DARK_RED = "#380000";
var DARK_YELLOW = "#383800";
var DARK_GREEN = "#003800";
var X_ALL = 150;
var Y_RED = 100;
var Y_YELLOW = Y_RED + 150;
var Y_GREEN = Y_YELLOW + 150;
var trafficLightsStateMachine;
function TrafficLightsStateMachine() {
  this.state = 0;
  this.stateMachine = new Array();
  this.stateMachine[0] = function () { drawCircles(DARK_RED, YELLOW, DARK_GREEN); };
  this.stateMachine[1] = function () { drawCircles(RED, DARK_YELLOW, DARK_GREEN); };
  this.stateMachine[2] = function () { drawCircles(DARK_RED, YELLOW, DARK_GREEN); };
  this.stateMachine[3] = function () { drawCircles(DARK_RED, DARK_YELLOW, GREEN); };
  this.process = function() {
    this.stateMachine[this.state]();
    this.state = (this.state + 1) % this.stateMachine.length;
  };
  this.drawCircle = function(canvas, color, x, y) {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(x, y, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.closePath();
    context.stroke();
    context.fill();
  };
}

function drawCircles(first, second, third) {
  var id = 'canvas';
  var canvas = document.getElementById(id);
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    trafficLightsStateMachine.drawCircle(canvas, first, X_ALL, Y_RED);
    trafficLightsStateMachine.drawCircle(canvas, second, X_ALL, Y_YELLOW);
    trafficLightsStateMachine.drawCircle(canvas, third, X_ALL, Y_GREEN);
  }
}

function init() {
  trafficLightsStateMachine = new TrafficLightsStateMachine();
  drawCircles(DARK_RED, DARK_YELLOW, GREEN);
}
function start()
{
  setInterval(function(){ trafficLightsStateMachine.process(); }, 1000);

}
```

```css
#page
{
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}
#canvas:hover
{
  cursor: crosshair;
  background-color: #191919;
}
#canvas
{
  background-color: #252525;
}
body
{
  background: #222222;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body onload="init()">
  <div id="page" onclick="start()" title="Please, press button.">
    <canvas id="canvas" height="500px" width="300px">
    </canvas>
  </div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: 1.added function start()    
  
2.changed line `this.stateMachine[2] = function () { drawCircles(DARK_RED, YELLOW, DARK_GREEN); };`  
  

3. you can call start on load of div instead of on click if u wish.